# View doesn't return anything in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just started to learn the laravel framework and have a strange situation here.

First of all in my `web.php` I have code like:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('users', ['uses' => 'UsersController@index']);
```

In my `UsersController.php` file I have code like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('users.index');
    }
}
```

I have a file named `index.blade.php` in directory `views/users` that has the same content as the default `welcome.blade.php`. But when I try to `return view('users.index');` there is no result (no error, or text) but when I try to `return view('welcome');` it works just fine.

The directory and the file truly exists.
I'm using Macbook Pro.

`welcome.blade.php` and the `/users/index.blade.php` content (default welcome page):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @if (Auth::check())
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
                        <a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Documentation</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If a view does not exist, laravel will throw an error. If you see only white page, that could be because your errors are not displayed. Check the log file for errors. `Storage/logs/laravel.log` or your php default log file. Try to misspell the view name on purpose and check the result, do you see an error?

Comment: @Hamoud when I misspell the view name there is only a white page as well. There is nothing stored in `Storage/logs/laravel.log` (file does not exist) and there is no logs in my default php log file.

Comment: Then, it'd definitely an error that is not displayed.  Check your .env file and make sure that it has these values:
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with file permissions. Change all the files to readable and writeable and it will be okay.

On macbook you can do it by entering this command in terminal:

```
chmod -R 777 /way/to/the/path/*
```

Comment: That's because laravel was trying to write to cache/views and laravel.log but did not have permission.

Answer (score 1):

if your laravel version is 5.1+

try this:

```
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index');
```

if it doesn't help you :

you could test step by step

**step 1** :
replace route :

```
Route::get('users', function () {
    return 'Is OK';
});
```

and run url : `localhost:port/users`

if Is ok

**Step 2**:

```
Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index');
```

and replace UserController index method :

```
public function index()
{
    return 'Is OK';
}
```

if Is ok go to **step3**:

create test.blade.php file in `resources/views` with content:

```
Is ok
```

and replace controller code with:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('test');
}
```

It will help you to find where is problem

Comment: Nope. Still the same situation.

Comment: @semkius I updated my answer , hope to help you to find your problem

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 are okay. But third step isn't working. I tried to chmod the file as well but still - just a white page.

Answer (score 1):

You Need To Give permission of Storage directory to 777 
Open the terminal and visit to laravel directory and change the permission chmod 777 storage

Answer (score 0):

1. On apache check the logs, see what's wrong:
   `/var/log/apache2/error.log`
2. Give 755 perms to bootstrap/cache/ and /storage folder.
   `sudo chmod -R 755 storage bootstrap/cache`
3. Generate encryptions key:
   `php artisan key:generate`
4. Check your /etc/hosts file, make sure it's pointing to right virtual host.
5. Restart apache:
   `sudo service apache2 restart`